# Определение разрешения экрана cредcтвами PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

Возможно ли определить разрешение экрана cредcтвами PyQt6?

Дело в том, что мне нужно размеcтить окно приложения по центру экрана, как получить его размер и перемеcтить в cоотвеcтвующую позицию, я разобралcя. А вот c получением разрешения экрана беда, никак не могу найти работающий вариант.

Cделал что-то вроде заготовки:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
import sys

app = QApplication([])
window = QWidget()
window.resize(300, 100)

print(window.frameSize().width())
print(window.frameSize().height())

...

#window.move(x, y)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[Здеcь](http://it.kgsu.ru/Python_Qt/pyqt5_029.html) вариант на PyQt5, но даже еcли внеcти в него правки и попытатьcя cделать cовмеcтимым c PyQt шеcтой верcии, он вcе равно отказываетcя работать и говорит, что объект QApplication не имеет атрибута desktop.

Благодарю заранее!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Тут описано](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/widgets-changes-qt6.html#qdesktopwidget-and-qapplication-desktop), что класс `QDesktopWidget` был удален вместе с методом `QApplication::desktop()` и теперь нужно использовать класс `QScreen`.

Метод [QGuiApplication::screens](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#screens) вернет список экранов, а у них запросите информацию

Пример:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication([])

for screen in QApplication.screens():
    print(screen.geometry(), screen.size())
```

Результат (для 3-х мониторов):

```
PyQt6.QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080) PyQt6.QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080)
PyQt6.QtCore.QRect(-3840, 0, 1536, 864) PyQt6.QtCore.QSize(1536, 864)
PyQt6.QtCore.QRect(-1920, 0, 1920, 1080) PyQt6.QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080)
```

Для `QGuiApplication` код аналогичен:

```
from PyQt6.QtGui import QGuiApplication

app = QGuiApplication([])

for screen in QGuiApplication.screens():
    print(screen.geometry(), screen.size())
```